# javascript base page form

Tags: javascript, forms

Lets say I have a base page called default.asp.  In default.asp I have a form:

```
<form id='levels'>
<input type='hidden' id='lvl0' value='0'/>
<input type='hidden' id='lvl1' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' id='lvl2' value='2'/>
</form>
```

default.asp calls an iFrame with the URL of: screen.asp and then screen.asp can recursively call another iFrame with the URL of screen.asp

I'm wondering if there is a way to read and write to the form from the iFrames (screen.asp)?

**Context of my issue:**

I'm trying to write to a hidden input element on each instance of screen.asp however, because of the recursion I'm having issues referencing the element (as the forms and the elements share the same name).  So my thought is to have the default screen (the base page that isn't called recursively) hold the values from each instance.

Let me know what other alternatives I might have using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being really easy to answer.

Per my example in the question:

```
parent.document.levels.lvl0.value
```

This does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your need for the iframe recursion. I'm not certain that it'll solve your problem, but if all you'd like to do is post to these pages you can use jQuery.post() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

If you really want a form you can also build it dynamically with jQuery:

```
performLogin: function () {
    var action = $('<input/>', { name: 'action', type: 'hidden', value: 'PasswordLogin' });
    var email = $('<input/>', { name: 'email', type: 'hidden', value: $("#email").val() });
    var pass = $('<input/>', { name: 'password', type: 'hidden', value: $("#password").val() });
    var rem = $('<input/>', { name: 'isRememberUser', type: 'hidden', value: $("#isRememberUser").attr("checked") });

    var newfrm = $('<form/>', {
        "method": "post",
        "target": "_parent",
        "action": location.href
    })
    .append(action)
    .append(email)
    .append(pass)
    .append(rem)
    .appendTo('body')[0].submit();
}
```